# Set values to zero in specific columns in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

In a data.table, I try to set the values in the columns; 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021 to zero, if the values in column ID **and** Score are identical.

This would be an example data.table:

```
library(data.table)

data = data.table(
  ID = c("a1", "a2", "a2", "a1", "a2", "a1", "a1"),
  Score = c("A","B","C","A","B","C","A"),
  "2018" = c(3,5,1,3,5,6,6),
  "2019" = c(3,5,6,2,1,4,2),
  "2020" = c(9,6,6,9,6,9,9),
  "2021" = c(4,0,3,8,5,4,6))

data <- data[order(ID, Score)]
```

I tried it with duplicated(), but with that function, it deletes the whole row. I only want to set the values to zero as shown in the solution example data.table.

```
solution = data.table(
  ID = c("a1", "a2", "a2", "a1", "a2", "a1", "a1"),
  Score = c("A","B","C","A","B","C","A"),
  "2018" = c(3,5,1,0,0,6,6),
  "2019" = c(3,5,6,2,1,4,0),
  "2020" = c(9,6,6,0,0,9,0),
  "2021" = c(4,0,3,8,5,4,6))

solution <- solution[order(ID, Score)]
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `replace` with `duplicated` to turn the repeated values to 0 in each group.

```
library(data.table)

cols <- 3:6
data[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) replace(x, duplicated(x), 0)), 
                 .SDcols = cols, .(ID, Score)]
data

#   ID Score 2018 2019 2020 2021
#1: a1     A    3    3    9    4
#2: a1     A    0    2    0    8
#3: a1     A    6    0    0    6
#4: a1     C    6    4    9    4
#5: a2     B    5    5    6    0
#6: a2     B    0    1    0    5
#7: a2     C    1    6    6    3
```